# Candies withdrawal probability for a particular subsequence

Tags: probability, combinatorics

You are taking out candies one by one from a jar that has 10 red candies, 20 blue candies, and 30 green candies in it. What is the probability that there are at least 1 blue candy and 1 green candy left in the jar when you have taken out all the red candies?

Comment: Can you share your attempts at solving this problem?

Comment: @Servaes, Please see below my approarch

Comment: Can someone show a combinatorial solution ? 
We keep 1B and 1G aside. Permute the remaining 58.
So acceptable permutations are  58!/(10! 19! 29!) x 2 (for B and G permute) while the entire set of permutations is 60!/(10! 20! 30!)
Ratio comes to be 20/59.
What am I missing ?

Comment: @whisperer Your solution only considers the sequences lasting with WB or BW..
What about the sequences like WBB or BWW? 
A wiser combinatorial solution may be to look for the probability(say P) of the occurence of the sequences ending with R or R followed by an arbitrary number of B's or R followed by an arbitrary number of G's. The reqd probability will then be 
(1-P).

Answer (score 11):

Indeed.   We consider what would happen were we not to stop after drawing the last red candy.

The probability that the last of sixty candies drawn is one of the thirty green candies is $\tfrac{30}{60}$.   Ignoring the green candies, the probability that the last of the thirty other candies drawn is one of the twenty blue is $\tfrac{20}{30}$.

Likewise the probability that the last draw would be blue and the last not blue draw would be green is $\tfrac{20}{60}\tfrac{30}{40}$ .

Thus the probability that you seek is clearly: $\tfrac{30}{60}\tfrac{20}{30}+\tfrac{20}{60}\tfrac{30}{40} =\tfrac 7 {12}$

Answer (score 4):

I came across following solution but curious to see how others approach this problem:

Let $T_r$, $T_b$ and $T_g$ be the "draw number" of last red, blue and green candies drawn respectively. So the required probability here is $P(T_r<T_b \cap T_r< T_g)$

Now the event $T_r<T_b \cap T_r< T_g$ can be achieved in two different and independent ways, i.e., $T_r < T_b < T_g$ and $T_r < T_g < T_b$

$\therefore P(T_r<T_b \cap T_r< T_g) = P(T_r < T_b < T_g) + P(T_r < T_g < T_b) = \frac{20}{30} * \frac{30}{60} + \frac{30}{40} * \frac{20}{60} = \frac{7}{12}$

Comment: What do you mean by “the number of last red, blue and green candies drawn respectively”?

Comment: it represents the sequence number in the total draw. For example, if $T_r = 60$, this implies last red ball is drawn at draw 60.

Comment: Ok. I don’t immediately see how you got the probabilities like $P(T_r<T_b)$ so quickly, but I’ll think about. There’s a geometric way to think about problems like this that I might post, but if your probabilities are right, your answer is very quick!

Comment: @SteveKass this is solution provided in solution papers from where I got the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The following is almost certainly overkill, but what the heck.

If you think of picking red, blue, and green as corresponding to taking steps in the $x$, $y$, and $z$ directions on a three-dimensional lattice, each way of drawing candies corresponds to a path from $(0,0,0)$ to $(10,20,30)$ of steps that go one unit in a positive direction each.

In the picture below, a candy-sequence would correspond to a path of adjacent cubes from bottom left to top right that moves right, up, or away from the viewer.

[image]

If you reach the right-most face in the red area, you’ve run out of red candies first, so to answer your question, you want to know how many paths (going only right, up, or away) there are from the origin to the upper-right box that reach the red area.

Alternatively, you would want to know what fraction of the $\frac{60!}{10!\cdot20!\cdot30!}$ sequences do not correspond to paths that lie within the following figure.

[image]

You can often write recurrence relations for counting problems like this, but here it’s far more work then needed, and you seem to have found a simple solution.

Comment: Just came here to tell you that I love this visual

Answer (score -1):

$P(T_r<T_b)$ is not that simple to calculate.

So I was counting paths. Basically for given number of $r,b,g$, we have $\frac{(r+b+g)!}{r!\cdot b!\cdot g!}$ paths. Denote number of all path where $T_r<T_b$ as $F(r,b,g)$, we have: 
$$
F(r,b,g)=P_g(T_r<T_b)\frac{(r+b+g)!}{r!\cdot b!\cdot g!} 
$$
and
$$
F(r,b,g)=F(r-1,b,g)+F(r,b-1,g)+F(r,b,g-1)
$$
We can easily verify that $P_g(T_r<T_b)\neq \frac{b}{r+b}$