# Candies in a jar

Tags: probability, combinatorics

You are taking out candies one by one from a jar that has $10$ red candies, $20$ blue candies, and $30$ green candies in it. What is the probability that there are at least $1$ blue and green candy left in the jar after you've taken out all of the red candies?

**Answer:**

> $7/12$

---

My approach (wrong):

We can consider strings of length $60$ consisting of the characters $R$, $G,$ and $B$. For example, the string $RGBBR \ldots$ would mean that we first take out a red candy, then a green candy, and so on. Under this representation, we wish to compute the number of strings of length $60$ with ten $R$'s, twenty $B$'s, and thirty $G$'s such that there is at least one $B$ after the last $R$, and there is at least one $G$ after the last $R$.

Let's first place the ten $R$'s into their correct position in the string, so our final string looks something like this:

$$\ldots R \ldots R \ldots R \ldots R\ldots R \ldots R \ldots R \ldots R \ldots R \ldots R \ldots$$

As we can see, the ten $R$ positions partition our string into eleven segments (the first and last segments are possibly empty). By symmetry, each $B$ and $G$ is equally likely to be in one of eleven segments. Thus, the probability that there is *no* $B$ in the last segment is $(10/11)^{20}$. Likewise, the probability that there is *no* $G$ in the last segment is $(10/11)^{30}$. Thus, the probability that our condition is *not* satisfied (inclusion-exclusion is $(10/11)^{20} + (10/11)^{30} - (10/11)^{50} \approx 0.205$. Therefore, our final answer is $1  -0.205 = 0.795$, which is incorrect.

Can someone please tell me what's wrong with my reasoning?

Comment: Try with 1R, 2B, 3G and you will get $7/12$ and then you will understand what you missed.

Comment: see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1805078/candies-withdrawal-probability-for-a-particular-subsequence

Comment: In the first glance , it is appear that when you put a ball one of possible $10$ places , realize that we would have new places to put balls , .. Secondly this inclusion exclusion process seems very torturous. if you want , i can write a solution using inclusion-exclusion

Comment: taking your first part, as you keep adding blue candies, the probability that the next blue candy is not the last would keep increasing as you have more spots for the next candy. Easier is to see that the probability that a blue candy is not the last in the mix of $R$ and $B$ is $ \frac{10}{10 + 20}$. Similarly, that a green candy is not the last in the mix of $R$ and $G$ is $ \frac{10}{10 + 30}$ and that neither of them is the last is $\frac{10}{10 + 20 + 30}$. So the answer should be $1 - (\frac 13 + \frac 14 - \frac 16) = \frac{7}{12}$

Answer (score 1):

After the last red, we need one or more blues and greens in any order.

Imagine instead that we are **putting them in**, and first in will be last out. **So now we want red to be the last color in.**

P(first is blue) $= \frac{20}{60},$ followed (may be) by any number  of irrelevant blues before the first green.

thus P(blue-green before first red) $=\frac{20}{60}\frac{30}{40} = \frac 14$

Similarly, P(green-blue before first red) $=\frac{30}{60}\frac{20}{30} = \frac13$

Add up to get the answer of $\frac7{12}$