# Candies in jar, conditional probability

Tags: probability, combinatorics, conditional-probability

> You are taking out candies one by one from a jar that has $10$ red candies, $20$ blue candies, and $30$ green candies in it. What is the probability that there are at least $1$ blue candy and $1$ green candy left in the jar when you have taken out all the red candies?

This question appears in Zhou's A Practical Guide To Quantitative Finance Interviews. It has already been asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1805078/candies-withdrawal-probability-for-a-particular-subsequence) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4410707/candies-in-a-jar).

I have a question regarding the book's solution. Zhou defines $T_r$ as the round number when the last red ball is sampled, and similarly for $T_b$, $T_g$. The probability asked in the problem is then $P(T_r < T_b < T_g) + P(T_r < T_g < T_b)$. Next,
$$P(T_r < T_b < T_g) = P(T_r < T_b \cap T_g = 60) = P(T_r < T_b | T_g = 60) P(T_g = 60).$$
$P(T_g = 60)$ is of course $30/60$, but I don't understand the derivation for $P(T_r < T_b | T_g = 60)$. Zhou writes:

> Among the 30 red and blue candies, each candy is again equally likely to be the last candy, and there are 20 blue candies, so $P(T_r < T_b | T_g = 60) = \frac{20}{30}$.

I don't get why we can just forget about the 30 green candies. On the event $T_g = 60$, the last candy is green, but the times for the $29$ other green candies are still random.
I'd like to see a more rigorous argument that $P(T_r < T_b | T_g = 60) = \frac{20}{30}$.

Comment: That argument is rigorous...what issue do you see with it?  Pretend the red ones are numbered $\{r_1, \cdots, r_{10}\}$ and similarly $\{b_1, \cdots, b_{20}\}$ for the blue ones.  All $30!$ permutations are equally probable and there are $29!$ that end with any specified ball.  The rest follows by adding the successful events.

Comment: The placement of the green balls is irrelevant.  The argument only considers the red and blue balls.  Since all permutations are equally probable, knowing that you drew a green ball first (say) has no effect on the distribution of the other colors.

Comment: If it’s clearer, among 30 red and blue candies, each is equally likely to be the last non-green candy that is drawn

Comment: We put 60 candies on a raw, and we take candies, starting from the left, and we continue, continue, until we get all red candies. Ohhh, be simple ! Start from the right, and simply stop when you get the first red candy.  If the last candy (on the right) is green we can remove all other green candy from the raw. The positions of all those 29 green candies has no impact for our problem. It remains 10 red candies plus 20 blue candies (plus the only green candy on the right).